# What does Ctrl + Shift + RMB (extrude) do?

Tags: modeling, extrude

The documentation says that Ctrl + RMB (in Edit Mode) can create vertices, faces and polygons, as well as extrude existing ones.
But the description about Ctrl + Shift + RMB is not entirely clear.
What does this feature add?

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> limits the rotation of the first edge.
Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> rotates the first edge slightly towards the new edge, while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> stays in place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This extrudes to where you click with the mouse pointer cursor (not the blender cursor).  The difference between using shift and not using shift is shown below in the animations.

Ctrl + RMB
[image: Ctrl + RMB]

Ctrl + Shift + RMB
[image: Ctrl + Shift + RMB]

As you can see using shift does not rotate the "extruded from face" to create a more gradual angle.